# Remove an array item from Nested array using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Looking to remove an array item from the nested array if subset array have value a **null** or 0(zero) using lodash. I tried filter but I am looking for best way in term of performance.

```js
const arr = [["a","b","c"],["f","r","p",0],["r",22,null,"t"],["d","e","f"]];
console.log("arr", arr);
// output should be [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `some()`

```js
const arr = [["a","b","c"],["f","r","p",0],["r",22,null,"t"],["d","e","f"]];

let res = arr.filter(x => !x.some(a => a === null || a === 0))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

- With `lodash` : `filter` and `includes` functions:

```js
const arr = [["a","b","c"],["f","r","p",0],["r",22,null,"t"],["d","e","f"]];
const result = _.filter(arr, x => !_.includes(x, null) && !_.includes(x, 0))
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.14/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

- With `ES6` : `filter` and `some` functions:

```js
const arr = [["a","b","c"],["f","r","p",0],["r",22,null,"t"],["d","e","f"]];
const result = arr.filter( x => !x.some(s => s === null || s === 0))
console.log(result)
```

- With `ES6` : `reduce`:

```js
const arr = [["a","b","c"],["f","r","p",0],["r",22,null,"t"],["d","e","f"]];
const result = arr.reduce( (acc, c) => {
  if(c.some(x => x === null || x === 0)) {
    return acc
  }
  return [...acc, c]
},[])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `filter()` and `some()`.

**Please Note:** The following solution will also work for other ***falsy*** inputs like `""` and `undefined`.

**Using Lodash**:

```js
const arr = [["a","b","c"],["f","r","p",0],["r",22,null,"t"],["d","e","f"],["d",undefined,"f"],["d","e","f",""]];
var res = _.filter(arr, a => !a.some(i => !i));
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.14/lodash.core.min.js" integrity="sha256-NAQPwApfC7Ky1Y54LjXf7UrUQFbkmBEPFh/7F7Zbew4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Using Vanilla JS**:

```js
const arr = [["a","b","c"],["f","r","p",0],["r",22,null,"t"],["d","e","f"],["d",undefined,"f"],["d","e","f",""]];
var res = arr.filter(a => !a.some(i => !i));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//cost will not let modify the variable
let arr = [["a","b","c"],["f","r","p",0],["r",22,null,"t"],["d","e","f"]];


arr  = arr.filter(aItem=>{
   //compact will remove null, 0 , undefined values from array item
   return aItem.length===_.compact(aItem).length;
});

console.log("...arr",arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.14/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```